# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this,

table name:transaction_tbl

[image]

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] @startdate NVARCHAR(100),
                             @enddate   NVARCHAR(100)
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT t.PlateNo
      FROM   Transaction_tbl t
      WHERE  dtime BETWEEN @startdate + ' 00.01.00.00' AND @enddate + ' 23:59.59.00'
  END
```

while executing this I am getting this error

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

I am trying to pass my start date with starting time and end date with end time of the day,,

Comment: Where did you ever see `00.01.00.00` as a recognized time format? Why are you passing dates as `NVARCHAR(100)`? Why is your query ignoring rows with times at midnight (or less than a minute from midnight)

Comment: sory sir i given start date+ 00:01:00.000 and end date + 23:59:59.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add time to your datetime values, just use `DATEADD`.

```
WHERE dtime BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, 1, @startdate) 
    AND DATEADD(hour, 23, DATEADD(minute, 59, DATEADD(second, 59, @enddate)))
```

You can find the documentation for this [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Comment: Ah, I just saw now that your `@startdate` and `@enddate` are nvarchar. This won't work without converstion to datetime your variables. Although I would just change the datatype of `@startdate` and `@enddate ` to `datetime` at the begining of the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you passing in `nvarchar()` parameters if you intend to have dates?  Why not do:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] @startdate DATE,
                             @enddate   DATE
AS
  BEGIN
      SELECT t.PlateNo
      FROM   Transaction_tbl t
      WHERE  dtime BETWEEN dateadd(ss, 1, cast(@startdate as datetime)) and
                           dateadd(ss, 24*60*60 - 1, cast(@enddate as datetime));
  END
```

Using the appropriate types will fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

use ISO datetime formats:

1. declare `@d` as `datetime` = `getdate()`
2. declare `@DD` as `datetime`
3. select `format(@d, 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.fff')`
4. set `@dd =  format(@d, 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.fff')`
5. select `@dd`

Playing with format() helped to resolve mine.. I do not know which is standard (probably 112) but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create DATETIME variables, and then use them..

```
SET date1 = CONVERT(datetime, @startdate + ' 00:01:00', 120)
//same way, declare date2

SELECT t.PlateNo
  FROM   Transaction_tbl t
  WHERE  dtime BETWEEN @date1 + ' 00.01.00.00' AND @date2 + ' 23:59.59.00'
```